# Measuring Salesforce1 Mobile usage

Tags: reporting, salesforce1-app, salesforce1-platform

I need to be able to measure the success of implementing Salesforce1 Mobile. Is there a way of reporting on what records were created or updated via Salesforce1 Mobile?

Comment: You might be able to put something together using [`LoginHistory`](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_loginhistory.htm) and the [`LastModifiedById`](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/system_fields.htm) system field.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out the features in Winter '15? You need to have Salesforce enable Event logging but there is this mysterious mention in the [release notes](https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_winter15_release_notes.pdf) of "Salesforce 1 Adoption" as a file type in the Event Logging featureset. Page 191. This might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes thanks, I had heard that tracking access to records by login type was possible at a recent product roadmap event but there wasn't enough detail around it. Thanks for your link but it doesn't really give me enough info.